# Label property ContentStringFormat with binding doesn't refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'd like to have ability to change display format of a readonly data in runtime. I've found that Label has ContentStringFormat property. I binded a ContentStringFormat to a DependencyProperty but when I change it Label's content doesn't changes.

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Window">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Label" ContentStringFormat="{Binding ElementName=Window,
                  Path=StringFormat, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
     <Button Content="Add accuracy" Click="ButtonAdd_OnClick"/>
     <Button Content="Reduce accuracy" Click="ButtonReduce_OnClick"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using TestApp.Annotations;
namespace TestApp
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty StringFormatProperty =    DependencyProperty.Register("StringFormat", typeof(string), typeof(Label),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

     public string StringFormat
     {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StringFormatProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StringFormatProperty, value); }
     }

  public MainWindow()
  {

     InitializeComponent();
     Label.Content = 10m;
     StringFormat = "f2";
     OnPropertyChanged("StringFormat");
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private void ButtonAdd_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     var num = int.Parse(StringFormat.Substring(1));
     StringFormat = "f" + (num + 1);
  }

  private void ButtonReduce_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     var num = int.Parse(StringFormat.Substring(1));
     if(num<=0)
        return;
     StringFormat = "f" + (num - 1);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: the owner type should be `MainWindow` not `Label`, so it should be `DependencyProperty.Register("StringFormat", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow)...` Otherwise the `GetValue(StringFormatProperty)` will return `null` (but any exception will be implicitly swallowed) and `SetValue(StringFormatProperty, value)` will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you, but nothing changed.

Comment: it in fact changes the `ContentStringFormat` OK but even when you change the `ContentStringFormat` manually in code, you'll see that it also does not work. That makes the binding for ContentStringFormat nearly useless. If you try setting some value (even the current value) for `Label.Content`, you'll see that it works.

Comment: I can confirm this issue also happens in my project. The ContentStringFormat is only used on the initialization of the label. So in my case I will toggle two Labels with the Visibility property.